# Classify static_cast and dynamic_cast in the IR Code

Tags: clang, llvm, llvm-ir, dynamic-cast, static-cast

I have a question..

In the IR level of LLVM, is there any method exist to distinguish between static_cast and dynamic_cast ?

If yes, how to check it using commands in the IR level ?

I know that, in the clang level, there are some method already exist as below.
 -http://clang.llvm.org/doxygen/classclang_1_1CXXNamedCastExpr.html

Could you give me a valuable guide ?

Thank you very much :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. LLVM IR does not represent static_cast, dynamic_cast, or any such C++ source-level construct. Even ABI-specific hints may not always be present, for example Itanium under some circumstances does not emit calls to the runtime function.

Comment: So.. Is there any method to distinguish between static_cast and dynamic_cast ? Should I have to do something only in the clang level ?

Comment: You can make an educated guess, but it will never be 100% accurate. If you need to know about the semantics of the source C++ code, you *must* deal with Clang, not LLVM.

Comment: Okay I see, Thanks for your comment :)